# Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I want to use geolocation and direction function, but there is `google is not defined` error. the code is as below:

```
function loadScript() {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&sensor=true" + "&callback=initialize";
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }
```

It seems that the loadScript does not work!

```
var mapOptions = {
                zoom : 13,
                mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
```

The error jumps out from here. Is anyone who know how to figure it out? I need to use key to get the geolocation service, so I cannot use simple

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

Comment: Use popular tags to describe the language and technologies you are using. This will help people to find your question and answer it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you people are getting Error in console then here is the simple solution that I applied.

include the script files in given sequence..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

You must first include 'maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false' first then go for jquery library and remove it from below both (it will work.) I hope it will definitely work.

Comment: If you reverse the sequence then any "callback" in the googleapis line to a JS function causes a similar error: "yourfunction is not a function."

Answer (score 12):

I tried it on my own with this code - it worked fine for me

**Dynamic with key**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html {  height: 100%; }
        body
        {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        #map_canvas { height: 100%;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
        }
        var myKey = "ENTER_YOUR_KEY_HERE";
        function loadScript() {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + myKey + "&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="loadScript()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Static without key**

```
  ...
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
   ...
```

When surfing through the net I tumbled over an important note!

> **Google Maps JavaScript API v3**
>
> The Google Maps JavaScript API v3 does not require an API key to
>   function correctly. However, we strongly encourage you to load the
>   Maps API using an APIs Console key which allows you to monitor your
>   application's Maps API usage. Learn how to use an APIs Console key.

See [**Google Maps API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/signup)

So, apparently you no longer need a developer key! I tried it with both - *static no key* and *dynamnic with key* - **both worked.**

Answer (score 0):

Google is not defined mean that your google map libary is not loaded which mean you are on https or http and you are requesting via http ot https so change it to https or http   .... 
mean if you are on http then

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

mean if you are on https then

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: You can use `src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"` to use file depending on `http` or `https`.