# using google.visualisation.data.join with doGet() - ReferenceError: "google" is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to join two worksheets by matching couple of columns. I load both of them into my script, but then I'm pretty sure I'm using the join method incorrectly. What am I doing wrong?

This is the entire code, deployed as a web app.

```
  function doGet() {

  //get the first table  
  var mainsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1pGxg4bEaoNzkL-JS22GO2-eo7K4UlxPNcjD4Na-6Eik').getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');  
  var maintable = mainsheet.getDataRange();

  //get the second table
  var subsetsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1pGxg4bEaoNzkL-JS22GO2-eo7K4UlxPNcjD4Na-6Eik').getSheetByName('Latest Rows');  
  var subsettable = subsetsheet.getDataRange();

  //join the tables - this is where i get the 'ReferenceError: "google" is not defined. ' error 
  var joinedtable = new google.visualisation.data.join(subsettable, maintable, 'left', [[0,1],[1,3],[2,4]],[],[2]);

  //make a chart from the joined table for display
  var joinedtablechart = Charts.newTableChart().setDataTable(joinedtable).build();

  //display the joined table  
  var siteProfiles = UiApp.createApplication();
  siteProfiles.add(joinedtablechart);
  return siteProfiles;
}
```

Is this a lead?

[Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500654/uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined)

Thanks for pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `google.visualisation.data.join` isn't Google Apps Script.

The visualization service is provided in GAS via the [Charts Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/). There's a [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/charts_dashboard) to help get you started.

Instead, build your 'joined' dataTable with a function that emulates the behavior of `google.visualisation.data.join`, and returns a combined `DataTable`. You could probably adapt the `buildFromSpreadsheet(range)` example from the [Script Examples site](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/uiapp-examples-code-snippets/charts).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I've followed the tutorial, it's helpful and as far as I see my code is fine apart from the join attempt. Does this mean I will not be able to use the google.visualisation.data.join in my script at all?

Comment: No, you won't be able to call any external javascript service directly from UiApp code. I've added to the answer... you'll need to make your own 'join'.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. Uncomment to check if individual tables are returned properly (which was the problem in my case).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['table']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawJoin);


function drawJoin() {

       var querymain = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pGxg4bEaoNzkL-JS22GO2-eo7K4UlxPNcjD4Na-6Eik/gviz/tq?gid=178275599');
       querymain.send(handleQueryResponseMain);

       function handleQueryResponseMain(responsemain) {

           if (responsemain.isError()) {
                   alert('Error in query: ' + responsemain.getMessage() + ' ' + responsemain.getDetailedMessage());
                   return;
               }

           var datamain = responsemain.getDataTable();

//           var chartmain = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chartmaindiv'));
//           chartmain.draw(datamain, null);

           var querysubs = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pGxg4bEaoNzkL-JS22GO2-eo7K4UlxPNcjD4Na-6Eik/gviz/tq?gid=1728586563');
           querysubs.send(handleQueryResponseSubs);

           function handleQueryResponseSubs(responsesubs) {

               if (responsesubs.isError()) {
                   alert('Error in query: ' + responsesubs.getMessage() + ' ' + responsesubs.getDetailedMessage());
                   return;
                   }

               var datasubs = responsesubs.getDataTable();

//               var chartsubs = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chartsubsdiv'));
//               chartsubs.draw(datasubs, null);

               var joineddt = google.visualization.data.join(datamain, datasubs, 'inner', [[1,0],[3,1],[4,2]],[2],[2]);

               var chartjoin = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chartjoindiv'));
               chartjoin.draw(joineddt, null);
               }
          }
    }       


    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
<!--        <div id="chartmaindiv"></div>
    <div id="chartsubsdiv"></div>
-->
    <div id="chartjoindiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```