# ng-include not working for html with javascript in it

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps

**This is my HTML Code along with the javascript**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <style>
        #map-canvas {
            height:400px;
            width:600px;
        }
        .controls {
            margin-top: 16px;
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            height: 32px;
            outline: none;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        }
        #pac-input {
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
            width: 400px;
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: 300;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }
        #pac-input:focus {
            border-color: #4d90fe;
            margin-left: -1px;
            padding-left: 14px;
            /* Regular padding-left + 1. */
            width: 401px;
        }
        .pac-container {
            font-family: Roboto;
        }
        #type-selector {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #4d90fe;
            padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
        }
        #type-selector label {
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var map;
        function initialize() {

            var markers = [];
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                    new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
                    new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
            map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

            // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
            var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
                    (
                            document.getElementById('pac-input'));
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

            var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
                    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ (input));

            // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
            // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
            google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {

                var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

                for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
                    marker.setMap(null);
                }

                markers = [];
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {

                    // Create a marker for each place.
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        title: place.name,
                        position: place.geometry.location
                    });

                    markers.push(marker);

                    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                }

                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                var myLatLng = event.latLng;
                var lat = myLatLng.lat();
                var lng = myLatLng.lng();
                var x = 'Latitude is =' + lat + 'Longitude is=' + lng;
                var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("lat");
                TheTextBox.value = lat;
                var TheTextBox1 = document.getElementById("long");
                TheTextBox1.value = lng;
                // alert(x);
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<input type="text" name="lat" id="lat">
<input type="text" name="long" id="long">

</body>
</html>
```

I have a angular app in place which calls various views on click event and it is handled by `$locationprovider` and `$routeprovider` from one single js file for controllers and all.

Now the problem is when I am trying to use the `ng-include` feature in one of the views it isn't working properly. The textboxes are visible but the map isn't. I even tried using the onload thing to initialize the function again which is in my original HTML page but still it doesn't work.

The error on the console is - `ReferenceError: google is not defined`

Which happens when the javascript part is not able to use google maps script.

Check this for info on the error : [Reference Error - StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500654/uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined)

**ng-include code**

```
        <ng-include
        src="'testmap.html'"
        [onload="initialize();"]
        >
        </ng-include>
```

Please let me know what I must do to rectify this.

Thanks for your time. Please let me know if you need more clarifications from my side.

Answer (score 1):

ng-include is NOT an iframe replacement. It is meant to add templates inside other templates for angular that may include calls to actual angular code.
You are attempting to include an entire html page, head tag and all into another page, which is not only invalid html, but also pointless unless you do it inside an iframe element.

I would suggest you refactor your code into a google maps angular directive.

Comment: Thank you for your response @SirDemon. I did read the documentation pertaining to ng-include on the official website and I was aware of that fact and i.e. why I have posted a question for the same. I am pretty sure many people would have liked to do something similar at some point of time. I am working on suggestion collected from sources on Stackoverflow only and I'll update this thread with results.Cheers!