# Google map is showing on browser but not in real device android

Tags: android, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic platform. I am trying to implement Google map in my app.Map is displaying when I am testing on browser but when running on real device on Android it is just displaying white screen. I have tried different number of things as recommended in different threads. I have applied changes in config file as mentioned in below link

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-maps/issues/10

but no luck and have applied changes using different number of meta tags individually as describes in other threads but no luck. In console I can see the error as 'Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined'. For this I have tried different thread as mentioned below

[Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500654/uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined)

but still getting the same error. I am not able to figure this error out.What else I am missing below is the code I am sharing used in my app.Index page code is

[image]

This is my controller code

```
    .controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.3000, -120.4833);

        var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var myDiv=document.getElementById("map");
        var map = new google.maps.Map(myDiv, mapOptions);
    });
 })
```

and below are the lines I have added in config file as recommended in different threads

```
<access origin="*"/>
 <access origin="http://maps.google.com"/>
 <access origin="https://maps.google.com"/>
 <access origin="http://*.googleapis.com"/>
 <access origin="https://*.googleapis.com"/>
```

Any help

Comment: For the next time, please provide the code like for the controller. A screenshot is not easy to see/debug and copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you haven't well imported Google Maps in the file `index.html`.

The issue is the line : 
`<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/..."></script>`

On a browser it will load this script : `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/...` since you are serving the file through http.

But on a device, you are serving the file through `file://` so it will try to load this script : `file://maps.google.com/maps/api/...`
That is not available.

So you need to specify https like this :

`<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/..."></script>`